# Pie/Bar/Line Chart in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, ecmascript-6

I have created my app using **create-react-app** boilerplate

I am trying to create a pie-chart using react-d3-basic which has dependency react-d3 which i have installed. 
I am trying the reference guides:http://esbullington.github.io/react-d3-website/
also:http://www.reactd3.org/docs/basic/#donut

The code in their docs is in ES2015 and I am using latest version of Reactjs. I am not able to convert it and use it.

> Can anybody tell me how to create a Pie Chart? Also, if better light-weight libraries are out there Do suggest me.

P.S.
 `var generalChartData = require('dsv?delimiter=,!../data/pie_test.csv')` what is the meaning of thiis code which they used in the examples.(taken from donut link provided above).

Comment: I like chartjs and would recommend using that — does this link help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709925/pie-charts-in-reactjs

Comment: @Jack I had shifted to Charts.js as i was not able implement react-d3

Comment: So you good, or do you need help with implementation?